# В приложении Android ListView теряет фокус при закрытии диалогового окна. Как вернуть фокус в ListView, после того как диалоговое окно закрылось?

Tags: android, view

Есть активность со списком товаров. Пользователь может выбрать товар из списка, при этом ListView получает фокус и выбранная строка выделяется цветом. При определенных условиях, открывается диалоговое окно с предупреждением. После того как пользователь закрыл диалог, ListView теряет фокус.

Как вернуть фокус в ListView после закрытия диалога?

Событие onResume() в активности с этим ListView не вызывается после закрытия диалога.

Пробовал также в OnDismissListener диалога вызывать requestFocus() для этого ListView, не помогло.

Еще попробовал в onDetachedFromWindow диалога вызывать requestFocus() для этого ListView, тоже не помогло.

Comment: А куда он, этот фокус, уходит?

Comment: Диалоговое окно получает фокус

Comment: Так оно же исчезает с экрана. Фокус должен кому-то другому после этого уходить. Возможно ему этот фокус совсем и не к чему, сделав его нефокусируемым все проблемы решаться?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Есть обработчик события onWindowFocusChanged, который вызывается когда окно получает или теряет фокус. В этом обработчике разметил вызов requestFocus()